# Binding a class method to a method of another class

Tags: c++, lambda, stdbind

I have two classes where one is logic and one is the model. After initializing both, I would like to bind a `b.funB()`to  `a.funA()`  where  `A a; B b;`.

```
class A{
   public:
     bool funA() { doStuff(); }
}


class B{
   public:
     bool funB();
    
    Template<class T>
    void bindBtoA((bool (B::*fun2)(), bool (T::*fun1)(), T *t){
       funB=std::bind( ?);
       // (fun1, t), (&T::fun1, &t), (T::fun1, t), ... ?
    }
}
```

How do I bind these correctly and get rid of "can't convert" errors *(I did use typedef in my actual code)*

An answer using lambda is acceptable. But, `funB` needs to be a callable as another engine needs to grab this *(hint: Q_INVOKABLE)*, so using `std::function` for `A::funA`  might not work for my case.

Comment: Unclear whether there are typos in your question, with all this mention of fun1, fun2, funA, funB.  _e.g._ there does not exist `A::fun1` or `B::fun1` as implied by your first paragraph.  Please provide an example of how you're wishing to call this and what resulting behavior you want.

Comment: I don't think you are using the right words. You don't bind two functions together, you bind arguments to a function. What you are trying to do is very unclear, but whatever it is, binding it isn't. If I had to guess, I would say that `bindBtoA` should be called `setCallback` and `funB` should be called `invokeCallback`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @paddy Apparently, I kept going with the argument names of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via the magic of [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), which would be hidden inside class `B` and type-erases the function to be called, thereby giving you the generality you seek.

Here's a fully-worked example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A
{
public:
    bool funA () { std::cout << "funA\n"; return true; }
};

class B
{
public:
    bool funB ()
    {
        return f ();
    }
    
    template <class T>
    void bindBtoA (bool (T::*fun1) (), T *t)
    {
         f = [t, fun1] { return (t->*fun1) (); };
    }

private:    
    std::function <bool ()> f;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    b.bindBtoA <A> (&A::funA, &a);
    std::cout << b.funB ();
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ff1KwwMpeveXuHbv)

I would think this would work with Q_INVOKABLE, but I don't actually know anything about it so you'd have to try it.  But if it does work, it's a good way to do it.

**Note:** With the code as posted, you are responsible for keeping `a` alive for as long as `b` is alive.  If you can't guarantee that, a better bet would be to use a `std::shared_ptr` instead.  Or copy `a` inside `bindBtoA` if that is a practical solution for you (which I'm guessing it isn't).

Comment: Nice, but it feels like it would be safer to take `t` by reference in `bindBtoA`. Perhaps: `void bindBtoA(bool (T::*fun1)(), T& t) { f = [fun1,&t] { return (t.*fun1)(); }; }`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Does it make any difference?  Dangling pointer, dangling reference, same thing.  Using a `std::shared_ptr` would be safer.  Anyway, I will add a note about the lifetime of `t` to my answer.

Comment: Perhaps not. I was thinking of the interface demanding an object and rejecting a `T*` that could be a `nullptr` but perhaps that's just giving a false sense of added safety.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Indeed.  But passing by reference would be idiomatic, yes.  I just went with what the OP originally posted.

Comment: In fact, I went with a wrapper when I was  trying to do this with std::function

Comment: OK.  I'm not quite sure how that would look but I guess the 'wrapper' in the answer I posted is the (capturing) lambda.  That hides the use of `std::function` from users of class `B`, which is what (I think) you wanted.

Comment: Yep, I was just about to resend my comment to thank you for putting exactly that in to answer as well. B is owned by  A,  (Control<-Data) but I want B to be agnostic of A. A binds logic to the handle in B (which isolates Qt from the rest of the C++ and ROS code. Is this a sensible approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that comment.  My class `B`, as posted, knows nothing about class `A`.  A better name for `bindBtoA ` would be `bindBtoT`, perhaps.